# Can't boot Xubuntu on my laptop

Tags: boot, usb, xubuntu

I have an old Asus eeePc series 900 (1 Gb RAM, Intel Celeron-M)
I tried yesterday to install Xubuntu on it, 'cause it was marked as one of the most lightweight ubuntu distros.
I made a live usb on my other pc (running windows) using LiLi usb creator v2.9.3 (i downloaded the distro directly from it)
Now the problem is that I'm able to boot the usb (i disabled secureboot from bios and marked the usb as the primary hard drive), but all I get is the distro blue logo. It seems like it is booting or uploading something, but after over 8 hours of loading screen i decided to ask you for some advice. 
Is it normal for the boot part to take so long? Am I missing something?
Thank you for any eventual answer (and sorry for any grammar mistakes, i'm not a native english speaker)

--EDIT--

Thank you guys for the interest.

I did as Elder Geek suggested (i didn't realize I could choose boot options by pressing esc).

Also, while I was waiting for the system to boot up I realized I could press esc during the Xubuntu loading screen and see what was actually going on.

Anyway, the system is now up & running, thank you all!

P.S: I found out there were many errors (i think they might be cause by the usb key being corrupted), but all with almost the same caption:

`buffer I/0 error, dev sdb, logical block 7962262, async page read`

and

```
worker [number] /path/ is taking a long time
worker [number] /path/ timeout; kill it
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! Enjoy your Xubuntu!

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the primary hdd back to the 20 GB SSD,

Plug the stick in your EEE, press ESC during the ASUS boot-screen to get the boot select list. Select your USB-stick as the boot device. And Xubuntu should start now and you can install it on your internal SSD-disk (or continue to use the stick as a Linux Live OS).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have UEFI firmware (if you have SecureBoot, you might have a UEFI system). If you do, then instead of using LiLi, format your USB stick to FAT32 and just copy the contents of the Xubuntu ISO file to it (don't copy the ISO file directly, extract the contents into the USB stick). Then just try to boot from it. This worked for me even on my old computer without UEFI, so you might want to try it regardless of it. But this does not always work.

And as @Elder Geek said, you should probably change your primary HDD back to the internal SSD.